# How do I create a file with PHP? (Ubuntu)

Tags: php

This may be marked as duplicate, but everything else I tried here didn't work. I am trying to create a file in PHP using this:

```
<?php

$con = $sup;
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/var/www/HDdeltin/" . $sup , "wb");
fwrite($fp,$con);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

I am using ubuntu(xfce)
What is wrong with this?

Comment: First problem: `$sup` is undefined

Comment: Additional problems: does your filepath exist? potential permissions issues, no error handling

Comment: Ok, I added $sup = "test"; it still doesn't work

Comment: So check the additional problems that I highlighted

Comment: Check for errors. What do `fopen` and `fwrite` return?

Comment: Yes, it exists. I also tried giving permissions by sudo a2enmod suexec to enable permissions for php, for apache. I got nothing

Comment: I got it: I got 3 errors and 1 notice. [Mon Jul 14 08:00:29 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant test - assumed 'test' in /var/www/HDdeltin/LoginSignup/PSignup.php on line 66, referer: http://localhost/HDdeltin/LoginSignup/Signup.php

Comment: [Mon Jul 14 08:00:29 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  fopen(/var/www//HDdeltin/notarealuser.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/HDdeltin/LoginSignup/PSignup.php on line 68, referer: http://localhost/HDdeltin/LoginSignup/Signup.php

Comment: p
[Mon Jul 14 08:00:29 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/HDdeltin/LoginSignup/PSignup.php on line 69, referer: http://localhost/HDdeltin/LoginSignup/Signup.php

Comment: [Mon Jul 14 08:00:29 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/HDdeltin/LoginSignup/PSignup.php on line 70, referer: http://localhost/HDdeltin/LoginSignup/Signup.php

Comment: Permission denied and Boolean errors

Answer (score 1):

```
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/var/www/HDdeltin/" . $sup , "wb");
```

is incorrect: normally `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is already `/var/www/`. Try

```
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/HDdeltin/" . $sup , "wb");
```

or

```
$fp = fopen("/var/www/HDdeltin/" . $sup , "wb");
```

depending on whether you want your file under the document root or under a specific location.

Comment: There is another error somewhere, too. Thanks for letting me know that

Comment: Care to explain why downvoted? The answer correctly identifies the error. Other issues have been indicated in the comments. However, this is an obvious error in the code: you cannot write to a non-existing directory, so without fixing this error the code cannot work no matter whether it has other errors or not.

Comment: 2 answers helped me, and this was one of them. Thanks!

Comment: Good to know the problem is solved. Could you please help me to understand why the other answer is any better than mine, apart from an obvious fact that the variable `$sup` is to be defined somewhere, as you most probably have been very well aware already? At least I cared to explain what caused the real error.

BTW, if any of the answers does answer your question, why don't you accept one of them?

Comment: I can't upvote or downvote answers yet, so it was other users. But I can tell you it helped me, so thanks

Comment: Thank you! BTW, did you know that you should choose one answer as the accepted answer? Then it appears with a green bird sign, so that other users know that it worked for you. I understand that all answers were useful for you, but the rule is that you should choose one.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$con = $sup;
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/var/www/HDdeltin/" . $sup , "wb");
fwrite($fp,$con);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

I don't know if you can use the last parameter **'wb'** for the fopen function. Try to use only **'w'** option then let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
<?php
$text = "This will be placed in your file.";
$con = "test.txt";
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/HDdeltin/$con", "wb");
fwrite($fp,$text);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

This seems to works if the folder HDdeltin exists, otherwise it will return an error.

`$text` would be the replacement of your `$sub` because you didn't declare one.
And I removed the `/var/www/` part since this is exactly what `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` should return.

Comment: I thought I had to do something like / . $ . to seperate the strings/variables, I'll try it.

Comment: You have to do that when you use Quotes ('), but with doublequotes (") you don't need to

Comment: Might be useful to mark this as an awnser for other visitors with the same question, that way they can see the awnser quickly

Comment: There are two answers that helped me fix this, Azrael's and alexander's helped me.